# Use keys and values to create new columns in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am attempting to flatten an API response that has a variable number of ['stats'] list results (some games do not have the same number or statistical categories as others).

I have spent a lot of time trying to figure this out but I can't seem to figure it out. I would like to use the keys from the list in the 'stats' column as new columns along with their corresponding value. Any help is appreciated.

```
example data = {
   "id":401238035,
   "teams":[
      {
         "conference":"None",
         "homeAway":"away",
         "points":35,
         "school":"Central Arkansas",
         "stats":[
            {
               "category":"tacklesForLoss",
               "stat":"8"
            },
            {
               "category":"defensiveTDs",
               "stat":"1"
            },
            {
               "category":"tackles",
               "stat":"61"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "conference":"Conference USA",
         "homeAway":"home",
         "points":45,
         "school":"UAB",
         "stats":[
            {
               "category":"tacklesForLoss",
               "stat":"5"
            },
            {
               "category":"defensiveTDs",
               "stat":"0"
            },
            {
               "category":"tackles",
               "stat":"39"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}


df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_records([dict(id = d.id   
  , home_away = d.teams[0]['homeAway'] 
  , team = d.teams[0]['school']
  , conference = d.teams[0]['conference'] 
  , points = d.teams[0]['points']
  , stats = d.teams[0]['stats']

  ) for d in data])

df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_records([dict(id = d.id
  , home_away = d.teams[1]['homeAway'] 
  , team = d.teams[1]['school']
  , conference = d.teams[1]['conference'] 
  , points = d.teams[1]['points']
  , stats = d.teams[1]['stats']
 
 ) for d in data])

result = df1.append(df2, ignore_index=True)
df_all = pd.DataFrame(result)
df_all = df_all.sort_values(by=['id', 'home_away'])
```

Current df_all:

| id | home_away | team | conference | points | stats |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 401207098 | away | Houston Baptist | None | 31 | [{'category': 'tacklesForLoss', 'stat': '1'}, ... |
| 401207098 | home | North Texas | Conference USA | 57 | [{'category': 'tacklesForLoss', 'stat': '5'}, ... |
| 401207101 | away | South Alabama | Sun Belt | 32 | [{'category': 'tacklesForLoss', 'stat': '5'}, ... |
| 401207101 | home | Southern Mississippi | Conference USA | 21 | [{'category': 'tacklesForLoss', 'stat': '2'}, ... |

Expected Output:

| id | home_away | team | conference | points | tackesForLoss | defensiveTDs | tackles |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 401207098 | away | Houston Baptist | None | 31 | 1 | 0 | 49 |
| 401207098 | home | North Texas | Conference USA | 57 | 3 | 1 | 44 |
| 401207101 | away | South Alabama | Sun Belt | 32 | 5 | 0 | 43 |
| 401207101 | home | Southern Mississippi | Conference USA | 21 | 2 | 0 | 41 |

Comment: kindly restrict your output data to the sample data you shared